# .htaccess redirect URL starts with /?/

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Google Search Console is saying that a site we recently rebuilt has a bunch of 404s, which all start with `/?/`, for example, `/?/AboutUs`.

When I redirect like:

```
RewriteRule ^?/AboutUs$ /about [L,R=301]
```

I get internal server error.

I tried it with the query string answer, that didn't help either (the URL I want to direct is not a query, I don't believe).

All of my server errors are of this kind, so a solution would be great.

Comment: The "Internal Server Error" is because `?` is a special character in regex and so `^?` is invalid (the regex fails to compile).

Answer (score 1):

**?/text** is part of QueryString in your url. You can not match against querystring in RewriteRule's pattern. You need to use a RewriteCond

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/aboutUs [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /about [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Since these URLs all appear to have an empty URL path, it may be optimal to use a `RewriteRule` _pattern_ like `^$` to avoid every URL being processed.